# Intercept WindowsKey + L (Lock) keypress in C#?

Tags: c#-4.0

Is it possible to intercept the WindowsKey + L (The short cut to lock the console) from a running application?

I've got an app that needs to catch that and display a custom window for about 5 seconds, then allow the lock to go through.

Can I do this in natively in c#? If not, can I do this with some sort of Windows API?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried getting some code written to intercept the Lock Key, were you able to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely doable, but I'm afraid you need to pinvoke:

[SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[LowLevelKeyboardProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[GetAsyncKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) could be relevant, too